# Why does show hidden files shortcut only work intermittently?

Tags: keyboard, finder, catalina, shortcut, automation

I am running Catalina on a 2015 13" Macbook Pro and at random times the default <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>
<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut for showing/hiding files will stop working. I read previous threads that mostly refer back to El Capitan or Mojave. I did find one thread that linked to a [Toggle Hidden Files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/toggle-hidden-files/) workflow. I tried it and the system pops up a window saying "Finder is not showing hidden files".

Any ideas as to why it might stop working and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across this recently and the way I got it working again was to "refresh" the Finder window.  Since there's no refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> like there is in Windows, you have to move out of the directory and then back in.  Additional, you can close the Finder window and reopen it.

It seems to be a bug within Finder

Comment: Didn't work right away, but it seems to have done the job. Hope they catch the bug. How is there no refresh?!

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer to a related thread, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/409800/176692, Apple has unfortunately given this shortcut double-duty in recent updates of Finder.  There are two new shortcuts that let you move backward and forward through a Finder tab's browsing history (i.e., they are equivalent to clicking on the left and right arrows at the top left of a Finder window):

- backward: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>
- forward: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

The latter unfortunately overrides the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> shortcut for toggling the hidden file ("dot file") view. However, if you are at the end of your browsing history (the right arrow is grayed out), then the dot file view toggle command will be recognized.  You can move to the end of your history, or open a new tab or window, to get access to the original shortcut.