# Keyboard shortcut to show hidden files on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

How do I toggle hidden files on/off?

In previous versions of OSX this was  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

It's not working anymore for me on macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> still works. Check Keyboard Shortcuts to see if you have a shortcut overriding the toggle hidden files action

To permanently show hidden files, open terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true; killall Finder
```

Comment: does not work in big sur

Comment: I can confirm it works in BigSur 11.1

Comment: work on bigsur 11.0.1

Comment: Works on Big Sur 11.4

Comment: On a French (AZERTY) keyboard the dot can only be typed by pressing `Shift` + `;`   So on a French keyboard the shortcut is `Fn` + `Cmd` + `Shift` + `;`

Comment: also works for me, flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm it works on Big Sur 11.1 (20C69). However I can also explain why it *doesn't* work sometimes.

Apple decided to create shortcuts to go backward and forward in the history, which is great! However they use the following key combinations:

- backward: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>
- forward: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

The forward shortcut takes precedence over the one used to toggle hidden files. So, if you want to show hidden files, make sure to be at the end of your history so you cannot go forward, that way you will be able to toggle hidden files.

Comment: End of your history??? What do you mean? I found an application showing hidden files https://nektony.com/funter

Comment: I mean when you can't go forward in your history (the right arrow is disabled), because you are at the end of the it :)

Answer (score 2):

on macOS Big Sur **11.1** I had to use `YES` and `NO` instead of `true` or `false` as parameters to:

```shell
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
```

Ex:

```shell
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder
```

Comment: fwiw, `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true; killall Finder ` worked fine for me on macOS Big Sur 11.1.