# Whole folder disappeared after running a rename command

Tags: command-line, macos, invisible-files

Using 'rename' from brew to look for special characters in file names and replace them with another character so we can upload to OneDrive.

I've ran this on other macs without issue. However, an entire work folder has vanished.

This was the command which appears to have done it.

```
find . -exec rename -s '/' '_' {} +
```

The folder is not in trash. `ls` shows the folder is empty. Is it possible to recover this?

Comment: Is it possible that you had two different folders that when you removed the special characters ended up with the same name? If so, then you will be going to your backup.

Comment: For some reason, all the root folders have got `._` added to the start now. So they were hidden. I can pick my stomach off of the floor! No idea why it happened, I literally copied and pasted the commands into terminal just how I've done it on 3 other Macs already. None of the commands rename with a .

Answer (score 2):

`/` is the directory separator. It can't appear inside a file name. The graphical user interface shows `/` in file names, but under the hood the name contains `:`, which the GUI won't let you use in a file name.

(The reason for this weirdness is historical: the GUI derives from historical macOS which used `:` as the directory separator, whereas the core of the operating system and the command line derive from Unix which uses `/`.)

`/` does appear in *paths*, as the directory separator, and `rename` operates on paths. Operating on paths allows it to move files between directories with very little extra effort.

`find` lists paths, and with `find .`, all paths (apart from `.` itself if it's listed) begin with `./`. So you instructed `rename` to move all files under the current directory to the current directory, with `_` instead of the directory separator. For example:

`./foo.txt` → `._foo.txt`
`./dir/foo.txt` → `._dir_foo.txt`
`./dir/sub/foo_bar.txt` → `._dir_sub_foo_bar.txt`

Since all paths listed by `find` start with a `.`, all the file names now start with `._`. File names starting with `.` are [hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments). To [show them in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406762/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-hidden-files-on-macos-big-sur), press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. To list them in a terminal, use the `-A` option to `ls`, e.g. `ls -lA`.

You can partly recover by running the opposite command:

```
find . -exec rename -i -s '_' '/' {} \;
```

Only partly though, because there's no way to tell for sure whether a `_` in a file name was originally a directory separator or an underscore. A plausible heuristic would be to treat `_` as a directory separator if there's a matching directory. Untested zsh code (note: this is zsh code, it won't work in bash):

```
function sort_by_underscores {
  local u=${${REPLY//[^_]/}//_/a}
  REPLY="$u $REPLY"
}

for x in ._*(O+sort_by_underscores); do
  d=${x%_*}
  while [[ ! -d $d ]]; do
    d=${d%_*}
  done
  echo mv -i -- $x $d/${x#"${d}_"}
done
```

If this looks sensible, run it again without the `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the result of my original command put a `._` at the start of all files and folders, I suspect my search matched all files and folders since the directory separator matches `/` (despite this not happening on other Macs) and then it renamed with the `_`, however I have no idea why it added the `.` which made everything invisible. It then couldn't go through subfolders as the parent folders had been renamed. Simply enabling hidden files to be seen and then manually removing the `._` fixed the issue. I ultimately manually renamed all the folders that used the `/` in the name.

Comment: @user2924019 The leading `.` is because every path listed by `find .` starts with `./` (apart from the leading `.` itself).

Comment: Of course, forgot about this. Thanks.